# Firebase storage download audio files in React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-storage, mp3

I'm using firebase/storage to set up audio file downloading/uploading. I have the audio file in my firestore storage already.

With the following code, I am able to get the download URL of the specific file:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/storage';

static async downloadMedia(mediaRef: string) {
    
    try {
        var storage = firebase.storage();

        var pathReference = storage.ref(mediaRef);
        
        const downloadUrl = await pathReference.getDownloadURL();

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';

        xhr.onload = (event) => {
            var blob = xhr.response;
        };

        xhr.open('GET', downloadUrl);
        
        return downloadUrl;

    } catch (e) {
        switch (e.code) {
            case 'storage/object-not-found':
                console.warn('File does not exist.');
                break;
            case 'storage/unauthorized':
                console.warn('Unauthorized.');
                break;
            case 'storage/canceled':
                console.warn('Upload cancelled.');
                break;
            case 'storage/unknown':
                console.warn('Unknown error.');
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

However, I do not understand how to use the firebase library to download the file itself with the URL that it provides me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution which doesn't involve me downloading the media but instead playing it directly with the download URL.

Using package 'expo-av'.

Hope this helps someone in my shoes!

```
export default function AudioPlay({ mediaDownloadUrl } : AudioPlayProps) {
    const [sound, setSound] = React.useState<Audio.Sound | null>(null);

    async function playSound() {

        if (typeof mediaDownloadUrl !== 'string') return null;

        try {
            const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
                { uri: mediaDownloadUrl }
            );

            setSound(sound);

            await sound.playAsync();
        } catch (e) {
            console.warn(e);
        }

    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
        return sound
            ? () => {
                    console.log('Unloading Sound');
                    sound.unloadAsync(); }
            : undefined;
    }, [sound]);

// ....
```